# How to maintain a strict alternating pattern of item "types" in a list?

Tags: python, list

Given a list of strings, where each string is in the format "A - something" or "B - somethingelse", and list items mostly alternate between pieces of "A" data and "B" data, how can irregularities be removed?

1. Irregularities being any sequence that breaks the A B pattern.
2. If there are multiple A's, the next B should also be removed.
3. If there are multiple B's, the preceding A should also be removed.
4. After removal of these invalid sequnces, list order should be kept.

Example: A B A B **A A B** A B A B A B **A B B** A B A B **A A B B** A B A B

In this case, AAB (see rule 2), ABB (see rule 3) and AABB should be removed.

Comment: Do you mean to say "If there are multiple A's, the next *set of Bs* should also be removed." In your example you have [A A B B] being removed.

Comment: That would be correct, although implied in the general rule of maintaining the alternation. If only one B were removed there, we would be left with: ... (valid preceding) A B (invalid) **B** (valid following) A B ...

Answer (score 3):

I'll give it a try with regexp returning indexes of sequences to be removed

```
>>> import re
>>> data = 'ABABAABABABABABBABABAABBABAB'
>>> [(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer('(AA+B+)|(ABB+)', data)]
[(4, 7), (13, 16), (20, 24)]
```

or result of stripping

```
>>> re.sub('(AA+B+)|(ABB+)', '', data)
ABABABABABABABABAB
```

Answer (score 2):

The drunk-on-itertools solution:

```
>>> s = 'ABABAABABABABABBABABAABBABAB'
>>> from itertools import groupby, takewhile, islice, repeat, chain
>>> groups = (list(g) for k,g in groupby(s))
>>> pairs = takewhile(bool, (list(islice(groups, 2)) for _ in repeat(None)))
>>> kept_pairs = (p for p in pairs if len(p[0]) == len(p[1]) == 1)
>>> final = list(chain(*chain(*kept_pairs)))
>>> final
['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
```

(Unfortunately I'm now in no shape to think about corner cases and trailing `A`s etc..)

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it as a generator. Repeat:

- read as many A's as possible,
- read as many B's as possible,
- if you've read exactly 1 A and 1 B, yield them; otherwise ignore and proceed.

Also this needs an additional special case in case you want to allow the input to end with an `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def solve(strs):
    drop_next = False
    ans = []
    for k, g in groupby(strs):
        lis = list(g)
        if drop_next:
            #if True then don't append the current set to `ans`
            drop_next = False
        elif len(lis) > 1 and k == 'A':
            #if current group contains more than 1 'A' then skip the next set of 'B'
            drop_next = True
        elif len(lis) > 1 and k == 'B':
            #if current group contains more than 1 'B' then pop the last appended item
            if ans:
                ans.pop(-1)
        else:
            ans.append(k)
    return ''.join(ans)

strs = 'ABABAABABABABABBABABAABBABAB'
print solve(strs)
#ABABABABABABABABAB
```